# How do I accept the essential cookies from modal that is placed in shadow-root on a website using selenium and firefox?

Tags: python, user-interface, selenium-webdriver, firefox, cookies

I am trying to us Selenium with Firefox so that it opens a new window and then clicks on the accept essential cookies button. Using the inspection mode, I get the following properties:
inner html: Nur erforderliche Cookies zulassen
outer html: Nur erforderliche Cookies zulassen
CSS-Selector: button.btn:nth-child(1)
CSS-Pfad: div#consent-layer.consent-layer div.consent-layer__btn-container button.btn.btn--secondary.js-accept-essential-cookies
XPATH: /div/div[2]/button[1]

So far all of my tries did not work out. Here is an example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Initialize the WebDriver using GeckoDriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

url = 'https://www.bahn.de/reisen/view/verbindung/muenchen/hof.shtml'

# Navigate to the webpage
driver.get(url)

# Wait for the button to be clickable
button_xpath = "//button[@class='btn btn--secondary js-accept-essential-cookies']"
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, button_xpath))
)

# Click the button
button.click()

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

I also looked at other solutions of related topics, but they did not work for me.

Comment: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/

Comment: I open exactly one window. Thus, I am not sure how this could apply in this case (?)

Comment: `This website uses cookies` is located in another window and you can see it by looking at the html code of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button is placed inside `shadow-root`, to get internal shadow root structure, you should get it's host first and then get `shadowRoot` property.

Shadow host in current example is first element with tag `div`. (Doesn't seem to have unique attributes)

`get_shadow_root` function gets shadow root from host, using JS executor.

[More about Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_shadow_DOM)

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
timeout = 10
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)

def get_shadow_root(element):
    return driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)

driver.get("https://www.bahn.de/reisen/view/verbindung/muenchen/hof.shtml")
driver.maximize_window()

shadow_host = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'div')))
shadow_container = get_shadow_root(shadow_host)
accept = WebDriverWait(shadow_container, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.js-accept-all-cookies')))
accept.click()
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element(accept))
```